# How does this Haskell code work? fmap fmap (,) <*> Just . reverse

Tags: haskell, applicative

Would someone help explain/breakdown the following code:

```
λ> fmap fmap (,) <*> Just . reverse $ "stackoverflow"
Just ("stackoverflow","wolfrevokcats")
```

It would be great if someone could walk me through their process of understanding the mechanics of this kind of code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's try to decode this pointless style obfuscation:

```
fmap fmap (,) <*> Just . reverse $ "stackoverflow"
```

First step: how this is parsed? Well, `$` has low precedence, so it's

```
(fmap fmap (,) <*> Just . reverse) $ "stackoverflow"
```

Also, I guess that the infix `<*>` has a lower precedence than `.` (one could check using the documentation or `:i` in GHCi). So, we get

```
((fmap fmap (,)) <*> (Just . reverse)) $ "stackoverflow"
```

Let's beta-reduce the `$`

```
((fmap fmap (,)) <*> (Just . reverse)) "stackoverflow"
```

So, the result of `<*>` is a function. This means that we are working in the `(->) a` applicative. There, `(<*>) = \x y z -> x z (y z)` AKA the S combinator from lambda calculus. We can beta-reduce that:

```
(\z -> (fmap fmap (,)) z ((Just . reverse) z)) "stackoverflow"
```

More betas, removing parentheses when we can:

```
fmap fmap (,) "stackoverflow" ((Just . reverse) "stackoverflow")
```

More simplification:

```
fmap fmap (,) "stackoverflow" (Just (reverse "stackoverflow"))
fmap fmap (,) "stackoverflow" (Just "wolfrevokcats")
```

Now, the `fmap fmap (,)` part. The `(,)` argument is a function, so this means that the first `fmap` is working in the `(->) a` functor. There, `fmap = (.)`. So, it's just obfuscation for

```
(.) fmap (,) "stackoverflow" (Just "wolfrevokcats")
(fmap . (,)) "stackoverflow" (Just "wolfrevokcats")
(fmap ((,) "stackoverflow")) (Just "wolfrevokcats")
fmap ((,) "stackoverflow") (Just "wolfrevokcats")
```

Now, the second argument of `fmap` is of type `Maybe String`, so the `fmap` is working in the `Maybe` functor. There, `fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)`. We get

```
Just (((,) "stackoverflow") "wolfrevokcats")
Just ((,) "stackoverflow" "wolfrevokcats")
Just ("stackoverflow", "wolfrevokcats")
```

Conclusion: pointless code is often pointless. To decode this snippet we had to run the type inferer in our head, recall *three* specific instances (even if they are pretty standard), and cope with precedence. No one should ever use this style except for deliberate obfuscation. (Surely not as a hiring puzzle!)

Comment: Thank you, that is an extremely helpful answer. How would you write the function then... something like `liftA2 (<$>) (,) (Just . reverse)` ?

Comment: @matthias `(\xs -> Just (xs, reverse xs))` would probably be ideal for readability.

Comment: @matthias As a thumb rule, when pointfree code is longer than the pointful version, it should not be used. 4castle's version is perfectly clear, and even shorter. If I really wanted a pointfree one, I'd use `Just . (id &&& reverse)`.